# Neo4j - how to display correctly french characters in the query result

Tags: neo4j

I am running this query returning this result set (Neo4j version is 2.2.3):

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:Language) where (upper(n.english_name_of_language) =~ '.*CRE.*') RETURN n.french_name_of_language;
+---------------------------------------------+
| n.french_name_of_language                   |
+---------------------------------------------+
| "cr�oles et pidgins bas�s sur l'anglais"    |
| "cr�oles et pidgins bas�s sur le fran�ais"  |
| "cr�oles et pidgins bas�s sur le portugais" |
| "cree"                                      |
| "cr�oles et pidgins"                        |
| "ha�tien; cr�ole ha�tien"                   |
| "muskogee"                                  |
+---------------------------------------------+
7 rows
91 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

How can I display correctly the french characters?

Comment: A database is served for write and lookup. the format in which you store data is up to you. if you need to convert it then you can do this at the application level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded the CSV file in a text editor (TextMate) and I did a Save As and selected encoding UTF-8. Deleted the data and reloaded and now all french characters are correctly displayed, like these:

n.french_name_of_language
adyghé
aléoute
araméen d'empire (700-300 BCE)
arménien
arménien
asturien; bable; léonais; asturoléonais
azéri
bamiléké, langues
biélorusse
tibétain
tibétain
amérindiennes de l'Amérique centrale, langues
tchétchène
slavon d'église; vieux slave; slavon liturgique; vieux bulgare
créoles et pidgins basés sur l'anglais
créoles et pidgins basés sur le français
créoles et pidgins basés sur le portugais
tatar de Crimé
créoles et pidgins
néerlandais moyen (ca. 1050-1350)
néerlandais; flamand
néerlandais; flamand
égyptien
élamite
espéranto
éwé
éwondo
féroïen
géorgien
géorgien
gaélique; gaélique écossais
suisse alémanique; alémanique; alsacien
haïtien; créole haïtien
hébreu
indonésien
indo-européennes, langues
judéo-persan
judéo-arabe
coréen
kpellé
carélien
judéo-espagnol
macédonien
macédonien
austronésiennes, langues
mendé
langues non codées
moré
nord-amérindiennes, langues
ndébélé du Sud
ndébélé du Nord
népalais
nigéro-kordofaniennes, langues
niué
norvégien nynorsk; nynorsk, norvégien
norvégien bokmål
norvégien
nyankolé
phénicien
réservée à l'usage local
aroumain; macédo-roumain
sud-amérindiennes, langues
écossais
sémitiques, langues
sino-tibétaines, langues
soninké
sérère
sumérien
suédois
télougou
tigré
indéterminée
zandé, langues

Answer (score 1):

Are you on GNU/Linux, mac or on windows ?

If you are on an unix like, can you give me the result of 'locale' & 'env'command into a terminal ?

How do you have create your data and with each encoding ?

When I create a node with the browser or my command line, my query result is good :

```
simard@fermat:neo4j-community-2.2.3 # bin/neo4j-shell 
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Test) return n;
+------------------------+
| n                      |
+------------------------+
| Node[0]{name:"Benoît"} |
+------------------------+
1 row
260 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ exit

bsimard@fermat:neo4j-community-2.2.3 # env | grep UTF
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
MDM_LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

bsimard@fermat:neo4j-community-2.2.3 # locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=fr:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=


neo4j-sh (?)$ create (n:Test {name:'ééé'});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 1
17 ms

neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Test) return n;
+------------------------+
| n                      |
+------------------------+
| Node[3420]{name:"ééé"} |
+------------------------+
1 row
19 ms
```

Comment: What is the result if you do "create (n:Test {name:'ééé'});" and after "match(n:Test) return n" ?

If result is good, your problem come from your data. You should have saved your string in ISO-8859 into the database, and console display UTF8

Comment: I did the test you suggested and the results are ok. I did another edit to rhe question to provide them. My data is an CSV file from an Excel file. I have Excel on my Mac but I don't know how to save the CSV file specifying ISO-8859. The CSV file loaded with the LOAD command to the database.

Comment: Cool ! It's important to use UTF8 in all your tool chain, included excel.